# not able to modify the text file value in winform application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on windowes form application..i created one text file..

```
Dim file As String = "C:\textfile.txt"
            If System.IO.File.Exists(file) = True Then
                If locid = txtvalue Then
                Else
                    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(file, True)
                    file = file.Replace(txtvalue, loc)
                    objWriter.WriteLine(file, loc)
                    objWriter.Close()
                End If
End if
```

in this two values is ther,,`txtvalue` and `loc` valu..if this value is not same,,then i want to replace my `txtvalue` with `loc` value.
`txtvalue` is the existing value in the text file
`loc` value is the new value from the code
after executing this code also i am getting both value,,not replacing existing value with new value..what s wrong with new code

Comment: How are you getting values of `txtvalue` and `loc`?

Comment: txt value am taking Using reader As TextReader = File.OpenText("C:\textfile.txt")
                txtvalue = Integer.Parse(reader.ReadLine()) end using

Comment: and loc value am taking from one combobox..

Comment: `file` is the string and file name ... `file.Replace()` will change the file name

Comment: so what i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I *think* you want something like this (Untested)

```
Dim NewValue = "Something to store"
Dim Path = "..."

If IO.File.Exists(Path)
    'Read existing value
    Dim Existing = IO.File.ReadAllText(Path)
    If Existing <> NewValue
        'It's different to the new value, overwrite it.
        IO.File.WriteAllText(Path, NewValue)
    End If
Else
    'File doesn't exist. Create it
    IO.File.WriteAllText(Path, NewValue)
End If
```

This avoids writing the file if the contents hasn't changed... Of course, If the data is small (less than megabytes), you're not trying to avoid conflicts with open file handles and you're not doing this in a tight loop, you're probably better off just writing it anyway...

```
IO.File.WriteAllText(Path, NewValue)
```

It's more readable/maintainable and the overhead for a one-off write should be negligible.